# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$, without using any $\sum\frac{n}{2^{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Problem: Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$, without using any $\sum\frac{n}{2^{n}}$.

I manage to make progress, but then end up always getting a $\sum\frac{n}{2^{n}}$. For example, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{2^{n+1}}$ = $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n+2}}$ = $\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n}}$, which is the sum we're not allowed to use.

Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the context in which you were posed this problem? (Like what class/textbook, and what recent topics did you learn in it?) This might help us pin down some techniques that might be relevant, because those that come to mind for me all end up involving the forbidden sum at some point or another.

Comment: Start with $0/2^2+1/2^3+2/2^4+...$ and multiply by $(1-1/2)^2=1-1/2-1/2+1/4$. We get $$(0/2^2+1/2^3+2/2^4+...)-(0/2^3+1/2^4+2/2^5+...)-(0/2^3+1/2^4+2/2^5+...)+(0/2^4+1/2^5+2/2^6+...)=0/2^2+1/2^3$$ All other terms cancel. So, your sum is $\frac{1}{2^3}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-1/2)^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fairly general approach.  Note that $n-1=\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}(1)$ so that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)a_n &=\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n-1)a_n\\\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} a_n\\\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty a_n\tag1
\end{align}$$

Now, take $a_n=x^n$, $|x|<1$ in $(1)$ and using $\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty x^n=\frac{x^{m+1}}{1-x}$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)x^n&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^{m+1}}{1-x}\\\\
&=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}\tag2
\end{align}$$

Using $x=1/2$ in $(2)$ yields

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{2^n}=1$$

from which we see that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{2^{n+1}}&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see how the generalized equation in (1) works, I'm just a little confused how you arrive at the last equation (1) from the previous step, if you could elaborate that'd be great.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  To arrive at $(1)$, we changed the order of summation.

Answer (score 1):

Render

$S=\dfrac{0}{2^1}+\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{2}{2^3}+...$

Divide by $2$:

$S/2=\dfrac{0}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\dfrac{2}{2^4}+...$

Now take the difference between terms with like denominators, e.g. $1/2^2$ from the first equation minus $0/2^2$ from the second.  This gives

$S-S/2=\dfrac{0}{2^1}+\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+...$

where all nonzero terms on the right side have $1$ as numerator.  The left side is $S/2$ and the right side may be summed as a geometric series, from which we then extract $S$.

This is essentially the way to **prove the sum of a series where an arithmetic sequence is multiplied by a geometric one.**

Answer (score 0):

Let $ n $ be an integer greater than $ 1 $, observe that : $$ \frac{n}{2^{n}}-\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{n-1}{2^{n+1}} $$

Which means it is a telescopic series.